# Get Latest Commit for AWS CodeDeploy to Auto Scale Group from Github

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

So I have an auto scale group setup behind a loadbalancer. I have circle ci setup to run tests and then push to the auto scale group on aws. But for the life of me I cannot find how to tell the auto scale group how to pull the latest commit from master branch when spinning up new instances. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to give CodeDeploy the commit id of the commit you want to deploy.

Comment: Please see my updates. Works great, been doing code deploy for years this way. Much faster than a S3 zip artifact, if you have a repo of any size

Answer (score 0):

First,  Integrating CodeDeploy with Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling

> When new Amazon EC2 instances are launched as part of an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling group, CodeDeploy can deploy your revisions to the new instances automatically. You can also coordinate deployments in CodeDeploy with Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling instances registered with Elastic Load Balancing load balancers

See 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html

Then, give CodeDeploy the commit id of the commit you want to deploy, via the CodeDeploy application console, in the deployment settings.

> Click Connect With GitHub, and then step through the OAuth process. A few different things might happen next. First, if you are not logged into GitHub in your browser, you will be asked to log in. Next, if you haven’t already granted AWS CodeDeploy access to your GitHub repositories, you will be asked to authorize that now. Once this is done, you’ll return to the AWS Management Console and CodeDeploy will have the permissions required to access your repository. **All that’s left is to fill in the Repository Name and Commit ID.** The repository name will be in the format “GITHUB_USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME”. The commit ID will be the full SHA (a 40-digit hex number) that can be copied through the GitHub UI. You can find this information from the commit history page of your repository.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automatically-deploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/

When configured as above, instances  that meet the deployment who criteria will automatically receive a new deployment on first launch and of course on subsequent manual deployments.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does it automatically by the code deploy application you set for auto scale group. If anyone ever searches for this.